# Joomla Logic PHP Query with 4 parameters

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

**Logic Query**

Hello,

We have 2 logic

a) **Customer been contacted maximum times:** Marking restriction on number of times a customer is been contacted. We have put in the maximum times a customer can be contacted as 2 by the vendor. Having this php code

```
$max = 2;
$listing = JRequest::getInt('listing');

if($listing) {
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."' ");
$nrSub = $db->loadResult();

if ($nrSub >= $max) {
  $formLayout = '<p><em>Sorry, This customer has already been contacted maximum number of times</em></p>';
}
}
```

b) **Maximum Number of times a vendor can contact customers in a form**

```
$max = 10;
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);
 
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').')')
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
    ->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
    ->where($db->qn('Username').'='.$db->q($user->get('username')));
 
$db->setQuery($query);
$counter = $db->loadResult();
 
if ($counter >= $max){
  $formLayout = '<p style="color:blue;">You have already contacted 10 customers </p>';
}
```

Both are working well - Now we have to set up a condition:- **in which a dealer if try to contact the same customer again whom he has contacted earlier also should show an error message**

Guess it would be based on 4 paramters

> Count submission and compare it with Max Parameter as 1
>
> Formid
>
> Listing
>
> Username

Trying this code - but seems not respecting in the

```
$max = 1;
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$listing = JRequest::getInt('listing');

if($listing) {
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').') FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."' ");
$nrSub = $db->loadResult();

if ($nrSub >= $max) {
  $formLayout = '<p><strong>Sorry, You have already contacted this customer</strong></p>';
}
}
```

so that it matches - if the username has already contacted once the listing id of the form - then should show an error message

May be the username parameter needs to be added in code - 1

Can someone assist, help and advise to achieve in desired - how to set up the logic query

Comment: i think you have to store values of dealer and customer when dealer contact customers with new table like contact_id, leader_id, customer_id, now you have to check both id after checking max count logic

Comment: Hello - Values are already stored in of user, formid, listing etc.Could you assist with logic statement

Comment: What are you expecting to get from COUNT(username)? That is going to tell you how many usernames there are.

Comment: Ok fine. So just before leader contact to customer put logic statement like select COUNT(*) from <table_name> where customer_id=<your id> and customer_id=<customer_id>. check this count if its 1 then we dont have to allow then contacting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use COUNT I think you should apply GROUP BY as well, like:

```
SELECT COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').') FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."' GROUP BY '.$db->qn('Username').'"
```